# How do I get Django PK value in a CBV whithout appearing in the URL?

Tags: python, django

I basically want the PK of the user who has logged in to my website. I don't want it to appear in the URL so I cannot use kwargs. But since the user has logged in already, I think there must be a way to access the user's primary key. Do you have any idea I can do this? I scoured StackOverflow for a long time but I did not get any answer to my query because most of the questions were asking how to get the PK when it is send in the URL. Please help!

Comment: `self.request.user.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can work with `self.request.user.pk`, or if you need the user object, `self.request.user`.

For example if you have a `Post` model with an `author` field that refers to a user, you can filter this in a `ListView` with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView

class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        )
```

You can only work with `self.request.user` in the methods of the class-based view, not in the attributes of the `View`, nor in a classmethod or a staticmethod.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).